# Xamarin Android Async Crashes

Tags: xamarin.android

I'm getting regular crashes on my app with the following stack trace

```
SquadFragment+<SetupViewAsync>d__12.MoveNext ()
AsyncMethodBuilderCore+<>c.<ThrowAsync>b__6_0 (System.Object state)
SyncContext+<>c__DisplayClass2_0.<Post>b__0 ()
Thread+RunnableImplementor.Run ()
IRunnableInvoker.n_Run (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this)
(wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object.8(intptr,intptr)
```

I cannot reproduce these on my device or in the simulator, can anyone help with these errors?  This seems to be happening since I've moved to the support v4 fragments.

```
public async void SetupViewAsync()
{
        Players = await SquadApp.Current.PlayerRepo.GetAllPlayers();
        Log.Debug(TAG, string.Format("Found {0} players", Players.Count));

        if (Players != null && Players.Count != 0)
        {
            // Create our custom adapter
            PlayerListAdapter = new PlayersListAdapter(Activity, Players, this, IsPurchased);
            PlayersListView.SetAdapter(PlayerListAdapter);

            LayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(Activity);
            PlayersListView.SetLayoutManager(LayoutManager);

            var itemDecoration = new SimpleItemDecoration(Activity);
            PlayersListView.AddItemDecoration(itemDecoration);

            if (Players.Count == 1)
            {
                TotalPlayersTextView.Text = GetString(Resource.String.one_player);
            }
            else
            {
                TotalPlayersTextView.Text = GetString(Resource.String.total_players, Players.Count());
            }

            NoPlayersView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            PlayersListView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            TotalPlayersTextView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
        }
        else 
        {
            NoPlayersView.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
            PlayersListView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
            TotalPlayersTextView.Visibility = ViewStates.Gone;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Do you have the code around SquadFragment+<SetupViewAsync>d__12?
Also, you definitely have the latest version of all the android support libraries?
Also, Also, check that you have updated to the lib versions in the Google build tools.

Comment: Just updated the question.  I'll check. Thanks